# Varnish: Select backend based on regex of hostname

Tags: varnish

Is it possible for Varnish to parse the hostname to determine which backend to use? I'd like to avoid having to do:

```
if (url = 'backend1') {
    set req.backend = backend1;
}
```

.. for all of them.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
set req.backend = regsub(req.http.Host, "^.*([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$", "\1");
```

.. but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible at the moment. You could use build scripts that build your varnish configuration automatically. The varnish developers are thinking about [dynamic backend declaration possibilites](https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/truly-dynamic-backend-definition-varnish), which would cover your use case. The dev is asking for comapnies that would use this feature, so you maybe want to tell him that you are interested ;-)